# SHELL command to ZIP only subfolders where folder name > 6000

Tags: shell, zip

I have a folder named images with 7000 subfolders in it named 1, 2, 3... until 7000.

I need to zip only the folders where folder name > 6000.

Is this possible?

I was trying to exclude folders like:

```
zip -r myarchive.zip dir1 -x dir1/ignoreDir1/**\* dir1/ignoreDir2/**\*
```

but this is too long to perform with 7000 folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of excluding, select only the ones you need. You can use the single character wildcard `?` to select subfolder names with specific length:

```
zip -r archive.zip images/6???/* images/7???/*
```

This will add all files to the archive from `images/6000/*` to `images/7999/*`